# Elasticseach: indexing 100k small docs per sec, more indexes with 5 shards seems to give a little better performance than 1 big index

Tags: elasticsearch

## Summary

Our use case is indexing 100k small documents per second, with a small search throughput of ~2-3/sec.

This initial version of this question was based on benchmarks run on version 2.3.1/2.3.2 where, in order to reach the scale needed, I ended up using more indexes with 5 shards instead of one index with more shards (we tried 1x, 2x or 4x number_of_nodes). This is not an issue for us since we already partition our data-set for other purposes, so it is easy to create one index for each partition.

I ran a quick benchmark on elasticsearch version 2.4.0 and the difference between 1 index 47 shards and 10 indexes 5 shards each is not big, but 10 index version still performs better.

However since the difference is not significant, this question is not so relevant anymore. However just the benchmark data might be useful for some people so please find below some details for those interested.

## Details

This article[Tuning data ingestion performance for Elasticsearch on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-elasticsearch-tuning-data-ingestion-performance) by Masashi Narumoto has some interesting benchmarks and I used prime number of shards suggested here 19, 47, 83.

> The tests also illustrated one other important point. In this scenario, increasing the number of nodes can improve data ingestion throughput, but the results do not necessarily scale linearly. Conducting further tests with 12 and 15 node clusters could show the point at which scale-out brings little additional benefit. If this number of nodes provides insufficient storage space, it may be necessary to return to the scale-up strategy and start using more or bigger disks based on premium storage.

Elasticsearch version 2.4.0 was used, cluster has 12 nodes, 16GB/8core/SSD digitalocean droplets.

[image]

At first old version 2.3.2 of the Java API (TransportClient) was used, then client was upgraded to version 2.4.0.

See below graph showing slightly better performance when using 10 indexes:
[image]

3x8GB digitalocean droplets were used as client nodes. Each node simulated 10 transport clients each with 2 concurrent requests.

Example bulk sizes:

```
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243143
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243143
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243235
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243143
bulk finished 7571, bytes: 5242948
bulk finished 7571, bytes: 5243040
bulk finished 7601, bytes: 5243354
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243235
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243235
bulk finished 7601, bytes: 5243354
bulk finished 7600, bytes: 5243235
bulk finished 7601, bytes: 5243272
bulk finished 7627, bytes: 5243251
```

Between each test:

- clients were stopped
- all indexes were DELETEd
- mapping changed
- clients reconfigured to use 1 index or 10 indexes and started back up

### Mappings

```
  "settings" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 47, 
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "refresh_interval": "30s",
      "index.translog.flush_threshold_size": "2gb",
      "index.codec": "best_compression"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "MessageRecord": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": { "type": "date"},
        "host": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "IP": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "process": { "type": "integer"},
        "username": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "email": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "sessionId": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "APIName": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "componentName": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "className": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "methodName": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "message": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
```

### 12 nodes, 1 index, 19 shards, 1 replica

**Shards**

```
curl -s localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v | perl -ne '@v=split(/\s+/); $h{$v[7]} .= "$v[1]$v[2],"; END{foreach $k (sort(keys(%h))) {print "$k: $h{$k}\n"}}'
db1: 3p,16r,15p,     
db10: 13r,5p,17p,    
db11: 16p,12r,15r,4p,
db12: 18r,11p,5r,    
db2: 14r,18p,6p,     
db3: 9p,8r,2r,       
db4: 10p,17r,4r,     
db5: 9r,12p,0p,      
db6: 8p,7r,1r,       
db7: 14p,11r,2p,     
db8: 1p,13p,10r,     
db9: 3r,7p,6r,0r,
```

**Sample shards**

```
blabla-2016.09.12_0 8  p STARTED 546347 390.3mb 10.135.32.20  db6
blabla-2016.09.12_0 8  r STARTED 565703 407.6mb 10.135.35.193 db3
blabla-2016.09.12_0 16 r STARTED 573101 493.9mb 10.135.34.141 db1
blabla-2016.09.12_0 16 p STARTED 536669 370.5mb 10.135.35.41  db11
```

### 12 nodes, 1 index, 47 shards, 1 replica

**Shards**

```
db1: 15p,34r,25r,45r,27p,11r,39p,3p,
db2: 42p,30p,20r,31r,6p,37r,18p,7r, 
db3: 42r,33p,32r,21p,10r,23r,9p,45p,
db4: 13r,24r,46p,34p,10p,35r,22p,   
db5: 1r,15r,24p,12p,36p,14r,39r,0p, 
db6: 30r,38r,20p,32p,44p,9r,22r,8p, 
db7: 38p,1p,2p,4r,14p,26p,27r,17r,  
db8: 13p,16r,2r,46r,26r,25p,37p,43r,
db9: 33r,31p,19p,21r,41r,43p,7p,8r, 
db10: 28r,40r,5p,29p,19r,6r,41p,17p,
db11: 28p,40p,16p,5r,29r,4p,44r,18r,
db12: 12r,36r,35p,23p,11p,3r,0r,
```

**Sample iostat**

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    71.73    4.15   49.15    33.17  3739.81   141.58     0.28    5.24    0.51    5.64   0.38   2.03
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00  1027.20    0.20  563.60     1.60 30052.00   106.61     2.10    3.73    0.00    3.73   0.33  18.44
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00   867.60    0.00  407.60     0.00 51499.20   252.69     4.19   10.27    0.00   10.27   0.37  15.06
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00   424.20    0.00  296.00     0.00 20040.80   135.41     1.74    5.88    0.00    5.88   0.40  11.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00   661.20    0.00  466.80     0.00 11922.40    51.08     0.19    0.41    0.00    0.41   0.36  16.66
```

**Sample shards**

```
blabla-2016.09.12_0 42    r      STARTED 574413 399.1mb 10.135.35.193 db3
blabla-2016.09.12_0 28    p      STARTED 557903 399.9mb 10.135.35.41  db11
blabla-2016.09.12_0 28    r      STARTED 557903 394.9mb 10.135.36.136 db10
blabla-2016.09.12_0 33    r      STARTED 412963 286.8mb 10.135.32.60  db9
```

### 12 nodes, 1 index, 83 shards, 1 replica

**Shards**

```
db1: 39p,24r,33r,74r,69p,51p,23r,8p,27p,15p,3p,11r,67r,0r,  
db2: 40r,42p,69r,7r,50r,56r,18p,65p,79r,77p,17r,29r,30p,54p,
db3: 78r,57p,32r,33p,80p,53r,9p,21p,68p,20r,59r,45p,43r,72r,
db4: 82r,81p,58p,22p,35r,34p,70p,21r,75r,64r,44r,54r,46p,   
db5: 24p,13r,36p,37r,25r,60p,12p,68r,1r,46r,62r,72p,48p,0p, 
db6: 32p,42r,19r,31r,58r,9r,56p,71r,79p,77r,20p,52r,44p,67p,
db7: 74p,38p,50p,73r,60r,26p,8r,61r,10r,15r,14p,2p,62p,3r,  
db8: 13p,36r,37p,73p,25p,12r,6p,47r,1p,49p,26r,61p,10p,2r,  
db9: 78p,57r,19p,31p,66p,7p,51r,41r,18r,70r,6r,55p,30r,43p, 
db10: 39r,5p,80r,28r,53p,4r,16r,41p,76p,64p,17p,29p,49r,63r,
db11: 40p,5r,38r,28p,66r,4p,16p,76r,75p,52p,63p,27r,14r,48r,
db12: 82p,81r,22r,35p,34r,65r,71p,59p,47p,23p,55r,45r,11p,
```

**Sample shards**

```
blabla-2016.09.12_0 82    r      STARTED 100491  88.3mb 10.135.32.114 db4
blabla-2016.09.12_0 82    p      STARTED 100491  91.3mb 10.135.35.169 db12
blabla-2016.09.12_0 39    p      STARTED 178524   145mb 10.135.34.141 db1
blabla-2016.09.12_0 39    r      STARTED 178524 144.8mb 10.135.36.136 db10
blabla-2016.09.12_0 40    p      STARTED 289205   220mb 10.135.35.41  db11
blabla-2016.09.12_0 40    r      STARTED 289205 216.7mb 10.135.35.108 db2
```

### 12 nodes, 10 indexs, 5 shards each, 1 replica

**Shards**

```
db1: 4/4r,7/3p,6/1p,1/3p,0/3p,3/2r,2/0r,9/2r,8/0r,   
db2: 5/4p,4/2p,7/4r,6/2r,1/4r,3/0p,9/0p,             
db3: 5/2r,4/0r,6/1r,0/3r,3/3p,2/1p,9/3p,8/1p,        
db4: 5/0p,7/4p,6/2p,1/4p,0/4p,3/3r,2/1r,9/3r,8/1r,   
db5: 5/3r,4/1r,7/0p,1/0p,0/0p,3/4p,2/2p,9/4p,8/2p,   
db6: 5/1r,4/4p,6/4r,0/4r,3/2p,2/0p,9/2p,8/0p,        
db7: 4/3r,7/2p,6/0p,1/2p,0/2p,3/1r,2/4p,9/1r,8/4p,   
db8: 5/4r,4/2r,7/1p,1/1p,0/1p,3/0r,2/3p,9/0r,8/3p,   
db9: 5/0r,4/3p,7/3r,6/3r,1/3r,0/2r,3/1p,9/1p,        
db10: 5/3p,4/1p,7/2r,6/0r,1/2r,0/1r,2/4r,8/4r,       
db11: 5/1p,7/0r,6/3p,1/0r,0/0r,3/4r,2/2r,9/4r,8/2r,  
db12: 5/2p,4/0p,7/1r,6/4p,1/1r,2/3r,8/3r,
```

**Sample iostat**

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00   103.87    7.07   72.41    45.14  5544.77   140.66     0.40    4.98    0.54    5.41   0.34   2.70
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    62.80    7.40  136.40    30.40 52532.80   731.06     4.47   31.10    0.03   32.79   0.40   5.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    73.20    0.00   30.40     0.00  5904.00   388.42     0.04    1.27    0.00    1.27   0.55   1.68
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    40.60    0.20   32.00     0.80  6009.60   373.32     0.05    1.44    0.00    1.45   0.55   1.78
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    44.00    0.00   34.00     0.00  6209.60   365.27     0.04    1.24    0.00    1.24   0.53   1.80
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    44.00    0.00   31.80     0.00  5554.40   349.33     0.04    1.23    0.00    1.23   0.55   1.74
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    45.60    0.00   35.40     0.00  6614.40   373.69     0.05    1.49    0.00    1.49   0.62   2.18
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    55.20    0.00   33.00     0.00  5828.00   353.21     0.04    1.32    0.00    1.32   0.59   1.94
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    94.60    0.20   96.60     0.80 34596.80   714.83     2.65   27.41    0.00   27.47   0.44   4.30
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    45.60    0.20   75.60     0.80 25184.80   664.53     1.55   20.39    0.00   20.45   0.45   3.40
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    45.60    0.00   32.60     0.00  6132.00   376.20     0.04    1.28    0.00    1.28   0.55   1.78
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    57.00    0.00   41.40     0.00  7424.00   358.65     0.05    1.31    0.00    1.31   0.52   2.16
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
vda               0.00    40.20    0.00   27.20     0.00  4672.80   343.59     0.03    1.25    0.00    1.25   0.60   1.62
```

**Sample shards**

```
blabla-2016.09.12_5 2     p      STARTED 270216 229.5mb 10.135.35.169 db12
blabla-2016.09.12_5 2     r      STARTED 291290 243.5mb 10.135.35.193 db3
blabla-2016.09.12_5 0     p      STARTED 266065 225.6mb 10.135.32.114 db4
blabla-2016.09.12_5 0     r      STARTED 273731 230.7mb 10.135.32.60  db9
blabla-2016.09.12_4 2     r      STARTED 295275 241.5mb 10.135.36.175 db8
blabla-2016.09.12_4 2     p      STARTED 295275 212.8mb 10.135.35.108 db2
blabla-2016.09.12_4 4     r      STARTED 280898   240mb 10.135.34.141 db1
blabla-2016.09.12_4 4     p      STARTED 265626 345.2mb 10.135.32.20  db6
```